# Write Bytes to file, bytes shifted

Tags: powershell

I have my bytes stored as string values
like this in file `D:\source.txt`

```
208
203
131
132
148
128
128
128
128
128
```

I just want to read them, and store in another file

I am quite new for powershell, so wrote program like this

```
$bytes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("D:\source.txt"))
    {
       [void]$bytes.Add([System.Convert]::ToByte($line));
    }

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("D:\target.zip",[Byte[]]$bytes.ToArray());
```

So from my undestanding it should get string value, convert it to byte
store it in ArrayList, convert ArrayList to byte array and wrote it to file

And everything goes ok, even if i do `echo [Byte[]]$bytes.ToArray()` i see correct value

But result file is corrupted, and when i check it byte by byte i see next values

```
-48
-53
-125
-124
-108
-128
-128
-128
-128
-128
```

Seems like WriteAllBytes shift my byte values by 128, but why and where?

I am not very professional with powershell, and i cant find anything related in documentation
So can you suggest how i can correct this?

Thanks you for any info

Comment: I can not reproduce. I suspect the problem lies in whatever method you're using to check your file "byte by byte". If you use `Get-Content "D:\target.zip" -Encoding Byte` what do you see?

Comment: [Demonstration](https://tio.run/##dVBda8IwFH3Pr7gUwRbWuNY9iEOwEzYGMmEW9lD6UNu7mRGbktzpuo/fXtM691IMnMDl5JxzTyp1QG22KKWfK43NfMjC64nFmAXjwCJkwc2EBWEfwzn8wBrJX6iSsCRwRrSrRkZ96Bw5fZLTDDY1oYEZPOHBX23eMSdY14ZwxxdKSjsKVRoeaZ3VS2GIAbzaLbJ86w6kKBFECcmf4HHF74XEdDp9xqxYWta4vUTPsxYA391tT7JXokhPa/CoKNzkP77coybrFqs7y57yPO@2U/4y1o990YIwkrJ9fo6mTL8h8S9ROVdJSyTpOS1WXS3Xetp/sEVmF6pctvRYK@QPSHFdoXsamyM "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, i actually found what is the problem.
Cause for corruption was incorrect library method for converting from java byte(values from -128...127) to unsigned powershell byte
And in hex redactor i`ve got int(8) representation, which is corresponds, if check in powershell(uint) bytes are shown correctly
Thanks for help

Comment: Your explanation for what ultimately happened isn't clear, but it sounds like the problem was unrelated to the question as presented here, the code in which doesn't explain your symptom. Please consider deleting your question, as it is unlikely to be of benefit to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i actually found what is the problem. Cause for corruption was incorrect library method for converting from java byte(values from -128...127) to unsigned powershell byte And in hex redactor i`ve got int(8) representation, which is corresponds, if check in powershell(uint) bytes are shown correctly Thanks for help